# Next number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

Be forewarned: this is a riddle in the spirit of riddles.

Given the following:

> ...4522222222255555555599999999

What are the next digits?

*Note: I did not specify the number of digits you should give, because, if you know the answer, you can continue to correctly add an arbitrarily large number of digits.

I could ask you give the next 4 or 5 digits, but you would probably want to give more than 4 or 5 digits.*

Hint:

> the next 7 digits are 999999999

...But why?......

> Sound out what you see...
>  3 dots, 1 four, 1 five, 9 twos, 6 fives, followed by 3 fives, then 8 nines.

Comment: How do I give a hint and how do I provide the (an) answer to the question?

Comment: You can [edit](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/31917/edit) the post and add the hint in the spoiler (it starting with `>! `)

Comment: Question was first asked on another StackExchange site, but it refered to a 'decimal expansion' there. We may be looking at a fraction here.

Comment: I don't see why this got so many downvotes besides maybe that the last hint was a little too strong.

Comment: The last hint is not so much "a little too strong" as "answering the question".

Answer (score 23):

It's the:

> digits of π, just with every other digit stating the number of the following one.
>
>  So 3 point(s), 1 4, 1 5, 9 2s, 6 5s, 3 5s, 8 9s, 7 9s, 3 2s, 3 8s, ...
>
>  To expand the sequence:
>  ...45222222222555555555999999999999999222888  ...